# How to disable child package from propagating error back to parent on ssis

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I have a master-child configuration. My master package calls the child package. Both the master and child have their own Event handlers which are script task which just pop up a message saying that its either "parent error" or "child error".

My aim is to cause an error on the child package and trigger my event handler which pops up a message saying "child error". The whole package execution must stop here and not allow the master package to trigger its event handler.

Is there any script task which can stop the package from further execution or any property that prevents the child from propagating the error back to the Master package? and I want the changes (Either property change/script task) to be present on the child side and not on the parent side.

Comment: "Is there any script task"?    Are you asking if one already exists, or if it's possible to create one?

Comment: I'm asking if it is possible to create a script tag to do so. Even property changes to implement the same would be good.
I want the changes to be made solely to the child package to stop the execution.